# Highcharts Plotline feature

Tags: highcharts

I was wondering whether it'd be possible to draw multiple y axis plotlines on specific dates using highcharts.

I have 3 lines with different colors, one from 16 Apr to 30 Apr and the second one from 30 Apr to 28 May, the third from 28 May to 25 Jun

something similar to this :

[image]

Thanks for your help. 
H

Comment: Unfortunately, `plotLine` is rendered across the whole chart, there is no `start` or `end` in params. Instead, have you tried to implement separate series as paths? You can disable [mouse tracking](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#plotOptions.series.enableMouseTracking) per series.

Comment: Thank you, I had not thought about that.